# Force .NET type to instantiate as COM

Tags: c#, com

Is it possible to force a COM Visible .NET assembly to instantiate as System.__ComObject, rather than it's .NET type?  The reason I ask is, part of my app uses 3rd party COM objects, but some of those, when written in .NET, get instantiated as their .NET types and break the object handlers I've created.  I have no control over methods used to create the COM objects.  Currently I'm using the following to create the objects.

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(objectGUID);
comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with those objects that is breaking?

Comment: Use the COM interfaces/methods, IOleWindow as an example.  The objects might implement one or more of several interfaces, so I'm checking to see if the object is one of the interfaces.  When instantiated as.NET types the COM interfaces aren't passing the checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, no.

The COM activation of managed objects is done in the same AppDomain as the caller.  IMHO, This is a nasty issue with COM interop in .NET.  There are several questions here on SO with all sorts of attempts at making this work.  I can attest that I've tried most of these to no avail.  Your COM API provider SHOULD be producing a PIA ([Primary Interop Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch.aspx)) to ensure forward type compatibility.  If they are not, you are going to have some nasty issues.

The only workaround I'm aware of as a client is to only use the 'object' type.  Everything would need to go through reflection.  Some things you still can't do.  For example, you would not be able to implement an interface.

I havn't a clue why this works this way.  It's caused me no end of problems producing a viable api for both unmanaged and managed code.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was afraid that this would be the case, as it matches my own research, but I figured I'd ask before looking into other options. Thanks again.